# CakePHP & Subselects

Tags: cakephp, subquery

I got app that need to be recoded in CakePHP.

I got following select with subselects:

```
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS item1,
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM portal_members) AS item3, 
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM portal_reviews) AS item3, 
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM portal_downloads) AS item4
        FROM portal_articles 
        WHERE 1 = 1
```

Anyone have any idea how to create that query using CakePHP find($type, $params) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If that is your exact query, I'd recommend doing it in four passes.

```
$item1 = $this->PortalArticle->find('count');
$item2 = $this->PortalReview->find('count'); // etc..
```

It might take a wee bit longer to run, but your intentions are much clearer and the code would be much cleaner.

Comment: This is the way I did it first time, but thought there might by more strict method. Thanks for reply. Will do this that way!

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code

```
$this->loadModel('PortalArticle');
$db = $this->PortalArticle->getDataSource();
$a = $db->fetchAll(
    ' SELECT COUNT(*) AS item1,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM portal_members) AS item3, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM portal_reviews) AS item3, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM portal_downloads) AS item4
FROM portal_articles 
WHERE 1 = 1'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The CakePHP cookbook contains some subquery examples here:

http://book.cakephp.org/view/74/Complex-Find-Conditions

Comment: Yeah, found them, but cannot apply them to my sub-selects

Comment: Dang Yo. 502 Bad Gate Way.